# How to update data using vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, insert-update

Can someone please help me to correct my code as I can't make my update button in userform works. Below are my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_update_Click()
Dim cNum As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim nextrow As Range

cNum = 7
Set nextrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
For x = 1 To cNum
nextrow = Me.Controls("TextBox" & x).Value
Set nextrow = nextrow.Offset(0, 1)
Next
MsgBox "Sent"
'Clear Control
cNum = 7
For x = 1 To cNum
For x = 1 To cNum
nextrow = Me.Controls("TextBox" & x).Value = ""
Set nextrow = nextrow.Offset(0, 1)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is **Uncompilable**, you have 2 x `For x = 1 To cNum` and only 1 `Next`

Comment: Just to clarify, You have a userform with 7 textboxes that you want to put into Sheet1 column C, then you want to clear those textboxes without unloading the userform?

Answer (score 0):

may be you're after this

```
Private Sub CommandButton_update_Click()    
    Dim cNum As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim nextrow As Long '<--| have nextrow store a row index, i.e. a Long value

    cNum = 7
    nextrow = Sheet1.cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row '<--| store row index of column "C" first empty cell after last not empty one
    For x = 1 To cNum
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & x).Value = nextrow '<--| set "current "TextBox value to nextrow
        nextrow = nextrow + 1 '<--| update nextrow
    Next

    MsgBox "Sent"

    'Clear Control
    cNum = 7
    For x = 1 To cNum
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & x).Value = "" '<--| clear "current" TextBox 
    Next    
End Sub
```

Comment: @Janice, did you get through it?

Comment: @Janice, any chance to get feedback from you?